# UI guidelines of Android applications (tab icons)

Tags: android, user-interface

I spent some time trying to generate certain tab icons using [Android Asset Studio](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html).
I was obtaining again and again strange results: The generated icons had the same shape than the input png file I was using, but they were either all white (for the selected icon) or all gray (for the unselected icon).

After verifying that my image indeed have a transparent background as required by the tool, first I thought there is a bug on it, but then I read the [guidelines for tab icons design](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_tab.html)  and they say there that tab icons have to be 'matte' (I spent some time trying to figure out what do they mean with [that](http://blog.pod1.com/wp-content/uploads/Men-women.jpg)). Literally: *Tab icons are flat, matte, and pictured face-on*, and the icons files I was using had color.

My conclusion is that Asset Studio (that seems to be the "official" tool to do this) is enforcing this convention. Is that correct?.
My main question is why I am not supposed to use colors in the tab icons ?, is it just an arbitrary decision trying to make look Android applications more homogenous ?.

I was tempted to generate my color tab icons using another tool, but I saw in the [same page](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_tab.html) examples of what you should never do with tab icons, and they show icons with colors there. So before taking a decision I came to see my stackoverflow friends for feedback.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android Design Guidelines are likely proscribing that all tab icons should be monochrome because the focus of a user's interaction with the app should be on the content, not the interface elements. Color is a powerful design element and a colored icon can draw too much attention to itself and away from the content. Monochrome icons allows the user's content to take a prime spot, with nav. icons playing a consistently supportive role in a user interface. Plus, the monochrome icons will make your app a good Android citizen because icons will be consistent with other apps and will look the way users expect them to look.

Mac OS's menu bar icons have the same design guideline regarding color usage. The problems there can be even more pronounced as third party apps put their icons there. If every one of them wanted to compete for user's attention by using their brand's (or otherwise intense) color, a menu bar becomes a theme park rather soon.

I'd personally stick with the monochrome icons, as recommended in the guidelines.

Comment: thanks for the feedback @ebukva. In case you have used Asset Studio before, do you know what could be the reason it is generating all white or all gray images ?. I tried given as an input black and white images but the problem is still there.

Comment: I haven't personally used Asset Studio before (I've been exporting icons directly from Photoshop) but it seems like the Asset Studio is enforcing the gray colors as recommended in the guidelines on the graphics it generates. The kind of image it asks for the input is an image with an alpha channel (transparency). So the idea is for people to provide an image that simply defines the edges of a icon shape (by means of what is transparent and what is opaque) without worrying about the precise shade of gray, different states, and subtle shadows on each of those. Those are generated based on input.

Comment: So if your generated image is ending up as a square filled with even gray color, export a transparent image (like png) and provide that as an input.

Comment: but that is what I am doing, the input is a png image with transparent background, is that what you mean ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Strange because it works for me: I select Source: Image and upload a transparent png that has red shape on top of transparent background: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5008894/test.png The Asset Studio based on that file generates 4 sets of different states which change the original color to recommended grays and white and it adds appropriate shadows. Example: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5008894/selected.png  and  http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5008894/unselected.png  I used Photoshop to export initial 24-bit transparent png file. Is same thing happening with your png?

Comment: yesterday I reported the issue here: http://code.google.com/p/android-ui-utils/issues/detail?id=112. I uploaded the input image I used for my experiments and the output obtained, so you can see exactly what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you keep the densities correct and keep them in correct ldpi/mdpi/hdpi/xhdpi folder you should be okay. I haven't yet used that tool and my UI works okay.